# Html..how to use information from one page to another?

Tags: php, html

1. So I asked the user to enter "First name" "Last name" and click submit and when they click submit it takes them to a different html page. 
   I want to say "Welcome "first name" "last name"

Update: 
html file....

```
  <form name ="myForm" action="index.php" method="post" >
      Please Enter your Firstname :<br>
  <input type="text" name="fname" value="" method="post">
  <br>
```

index.php file

```
<h1>Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?><br></h1>
```

But php file only says Welcome...

Comment: You need some help on `javascript` or `jquery` here..

Comment: You can use html5  localstorage.

Comment: Could someone give me an example of JS or html5?

Comment: Did you close your html form? you don't need to specify the method in the input tag, only for the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

you should use server side code. for example [see this form in w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_post)

Comment: in that example it says you email address is :: "blank"..How do I get your email address is : "input value'

Comment: in this example. your form send to server and then server get your form data then do process on it and then send it to your browser. if you want to write server side code and run on your system you need to install iis for ASP.NET or Xamp for php.

Answer (score 0):

Your form will redirect you to `index.php`. You will then be able to get the value of `fname` and `lname` with  `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Your html form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
     Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
     Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
     <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Your `index.php` should contain:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]." ".$_POST["lname"]; ?>
```

Note: Replace `$_POST` with `$_GET` depending on your html form `method`
See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp for more information.